# Node.js package installation error

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm

I had install Node.js 4.2.2

i am trying to install socket.io package using npm install socket.io

but the npm installer just keep running with no error output in console after 30min..

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does any other package installation fail like socket.io?

Comment: i tried different package all fail with no error in console..

Comment: Check your `npm-debug.log`, is there any error?

Comment: where is the file located? i cant find such file using the search function...

Comment: Actually it must be created on error in the directory from which you call `npm`

Comment: i am installing it on my desktop but got no such file...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96324/discussion-between-rashad-ibrahimov-and-mick-jack).

Answer (score 1):

Try to install some another package, `mongoose` for example. If it also fails try to reinstall `npm` by

```
npm install -g npm
```

Comment: not working too.. run npm install -g npm and it just keep running with no error.. like the screen above..

Comment: tried uninstalling/reinstalling and still it does not work... can i install the package on other computer and copy the files over?

Comment: Yes you can, for local packages, but I would not recommend to do it for global ones.

Comment: do npm install async --loglevel verbose shows something?

Comment: i added the screenshot for the command npm install async --loglevel verbose

Comment: Try then 2 things: first remove completely node_modules folder inside your project and then try to install any package. If it fails try to create a completely new project (in another folder, of course) and install some package there.

Comment: I am trying to install it in my desktop but there is no Node_modules folder on my desktop..

Comment: Do not ever do that. Make a separate folder for your project, open this folder, inside it init it with `npm init`, then install any dependencies there and store all your project files there.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
npm install -g npm
npm cache clean
npm install socket.io
```

Also check if you permission to create `node_modules` folder in the directory you run `npm`.

You can downgrade your nodejs to v.4.2.1 for example, don't forget to clean npm cache after that, and then run `npm install` command.

Answer (score 0):

First try to remove these packages and then install. Like

```
npm remove socket.io
```

Then

```
npm install socket.io
```

may be the incomplete installed files are blocking it to install properly

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `npm` anyway.

Try from link install:

```
curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```

Or you can compile it with make if you clone sources from [github](https://github.com/npm/npm)

Comment: how do i run this? using the cmd?